# Universal Translator

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I need help with my school project.
I can't get any further with the chapter "Speech to Text or Speech Recognition with a Raspberry Pi". (see below)
When I run the script "stt.sh", the script terminates and can not perform the recording.
Also need help with logging in to Microsoft Azure Marketplace and Google API.

Link:
https://daveconroy.com/how-to/turn-raspberry-pi-translator-speech-recognition-playback-60-languages/

Comment: What can we do to help you? Shall we also follow the tutorial and install the translator to see what could be wrong?

Comment: Yes that would be best.  To where it fails you have about 30 minutes.  or I'll share the script with you, maybe you'll see the errors right away. For setup you need just a Headset and the script from daveconroy
I send you also a faster guide: https://makezine.com/projects/universal-translator/